# MySQL update part of 1 column in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with a column "code" that has a value that looks like this for example

3_22_00418

I need to update this value to

3_01_00418

And I need to do this for all rows in my table

what I tried is the following:

```
UPDATE table SET
code = CASE
WHEN id='1' THEN '3_01_00418'
WHEN id='2' THEN '3_01_00519'
WHEN id='3' THEN '3_01_00647'
...
```

But this requires me to basically right all rows and I have hundreds of rows this will take a while.

How can I do it smarter?

Comment: You need a table with all old/new code combinations.

Comment: How to get value of x?  it's explain below:
...
WHEN id='1' THEN '3_01_x'
WHEN id='2' THEN '3_01_x'
WHEN id='3' THEN '3_01_x'

Comment: I don't understand from where those replacement values are coming.  Can you explain this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the values are all set in my table the column "code" has a value for every row that looks something like this 3_22_00418 and the _22_ is always the same and need to be replaced with _01_ in all rows

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen basically I need a find an replace for `_22_` to `_01_`

Comment: basically you can write a java code logic to do this and execute that query multiple times with different values inside loop

Comment: @OnkarMusale I need an sql query for this

Comment: do you have other table containing 3_01_00418 these kind of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function comes in handy here:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET code = REGEXP_REPLACE(code, '(\\d+)_\d+_(\\d+)', '$1_01_$2');
```

### Demo

If you are using an earlier version of MySQL, we can try using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` for a slightly bulkier looking update query:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET code = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '_', 1), '_01_',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '_', -1));
```

### Demo

Comment: really awesome brother

Comment: the first solution says 0 rows affected, shouldnt I add a where clausule or something?

Comment: @Michael You would only need a `WHERE` clause if you want to update certain rows.  By the way, my answers are working with the sample data you have provided.  As for other data, I can't verify that.

Comment: Yes I was using wrong version of MariaDB where your first solution doesn't work but the second one works fine. 1 little question how can I exclude rows where the "code" is empty?

Comment: Use `WHERE code IS NOT NULL`, or, if you also want to exclude empty string, use `WHERE code > ''`

Answer (score 0):

Using REPLACE function as per below:

```
SELECT REPLACE("3_01_00418", "_22_", "_01_");

EX: 
1) First way:

UPDATE table SET
code = REPLACE(code , "_22_", "_01_")
...
```

2) Second way:

```
  UPDATE table SET
     code = (case when id>=1 and id<= 100 then REPLACE(code , "_22_", "_01_")
                  when id>100 and id<= 200 then REPLACE(code , "_22_", "_02_")
                  else  REPLACE(code , "_22_", "_01_")
                  end
             )
    ...
```